# How does one insert <tr> into a <table> (using PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using PHP and I have a table that I want to populate dynamically.

```
<table>
    <tr>
         <th>This One</th>
         <th>That One</th>
         <th>The Other One</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>Final This</td>
         <td>Final That</td>
         <td>Final The Other</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I am populating the table data onchange, and I want the data to be added **above
the row marked with "Final blah".**

Each new row has data to populate each cell.

Is there some functionality that will do this with PHP, mayber leveraging some JavaScript?

**EDIT:**
I want to get a final product that looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
         <th>This One</th>
         <th>That One</th>
         <th>The Other One</th>
    </tr>
    <tr> Dynamically added row. Cells already populated from database</tr>
    <tr> Next row of data from the database</tr>
    <tr> The next row should **ALWAYS** be the last row</tr>
    <tr>
         <td>Final This</td>
         <td>Final That</td>
         <td>Final The Other</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Notice that there is a HEADER ROW THAT I WANT TO KEEP!**
I want to insert rows between the header row and the row with "Final something".
The last row IS ALWAYS PRESENT.

Comment: use some ajax and jquery to find the last row and add it over it.

Comment: Need to dynamically create the `tr` , add data to it & append it to `tbody`

Comment: Try using echo in your PHP perhaps?

Comment: What drives the addition of the row.  OnChange of what?

Comment: Doesn't matter what I change. onchange of *something* insert some rows into the <table> BELOW the headinng row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am getting your query :

```
 <table id="myTable">
  <tr>
     <th>This One</th>
     <th>That One</th>
     <th>The Other One</th>
  </tr>
   <tbody id="myid">
    <tr><td>Final This</td><td>Final That</td><td>This is your Last Row</td></tr>
   </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>

<button onclick="myCreateFunction()">Add row</button>

<script>
function myCreateFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myid");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    cell1.innerHTML = "Final This";
    cell2.innerHTML = "Final That";
    cell3.innerHTML = "I am inserted between First and last row";
}

</script>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kup307mv/2/)

Comment: No. That w3schools example is why I am asking the question here. I want the final row in the table to be the same and all new rows to be inserted above it, below the heading row.

Comment: But on second look, maybe that answer is the one I need. I just have to wrangle it a lot.

Comment: This answer seems to be ignoring my header row.

Comment: No rows are being inserted between the header and the final line.

Comment: The final row is ALREADY THERE. It's not dynamically added.

Comment: i think your question was **I want to insert rows between the header row and the row with "Final something".** @KenIngram

Comment: 1. Header Row

3. Final Row (always there already)

2. Put rows in between 1 and 3.

Comment: replace above code by going at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_table_insert_deleterow and run (Fiddle is working at my side, i do not know what is error at your side, just change your browser and try again)

Comment: You can achieve this with table.insertBefore(newRow, footerRow)

Comment: @SNTwain. I had to change your setting from JavaScript 1.7 to JavaScript to get it working.